# Отправка сообщения в чат Discord по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord-api, gpio

Может ли Discord бот написанный с помощью discord.py отправлять сообщения в чат при нажатии кнопки подключенной к GPIO пинам raspberry pi? Может кому попадался пример решения этой задачи. Телеграм пришлось отбросить по понятным причинам.

Я смог сделать проверку состояния кнопки через сообщение из чата, но как сделать чтобы скрипт сам проверял состояние пина GPIO и отправлял сообщение?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   push_button = 0
   if (GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN) == False):
      push_button = 1
      print('button PUSH')
   if message.content.startswith('!check_button'):
      if push_button == 1:
         await client.send_message(client.get_channel(chanel_ID), 'PUSH')
      elif push_button == 0:
         await client.send_message(client.get_channel(chanel_ID), 'NO_PUSH')
```

Comment: Все возможно. Сначала научитесь обрабатывать клик на кнопку. Потом сделайте простенького бота, который умеет слать сообщения. Насчет телеграмм... используйте прокси и не будет отказов по "понятным причинам"

Comment: Имеющийся бот уже умеет проверять состояние кнопки(нажата или нет), но только по запросу из чата. Где бы можно подсмотреть кусок кода на питоне, который отправляет сообщение сразу после нажатия GPIO кнопки?

Comment: Научились отправлять сообщения в чат? Можно в лоб решить: создать поток, в нем проверять состояние кнопки и при ее изменении из того потока отправлять

Comment: с потоком же жесть будет.. тут прерывание нужно